# Why does `std::is_function_v` not work as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, standards, type-traits

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
bool f(T&& v)
{
    return is_function_v<decltype(forward<T>(v))>;
}

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha
        << is_function_v<decltype(setw)>
        << endl;

    cout << boolalpha
        << f(setw)
        << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The outout is: (clang 6.0 & gcc 8.0)

>

> true
>
> false

But the result I expect should be:

>

> true
>
> true

**Why does `std::is_function_v` not work as expected?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove reference on `T`.

```
template<typename T>
bool f(T&& v)
{
    return is_function_v<remove_reference_t<decltype(forward<T>(v))>>;
    //                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

When pass `setw` to `f`, it's an lvalue, then the forwarding reference type `T` will be deduced as an lvalue reference to function. For [`std::is_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function), references to function (and pointers to function etc) don't count as function types.

---

<sup>BTW: the forwarding reference type `T` will be deduced as either lvalue reference or rvalue reference; and using `decltype` on `std::forward` would always yield a reference type, either lvalue reference or rvalue reference.</sup>

Comment: why would you forward it then remove the reference?  Why would you even use decltype at all instead of just remove ref directly on type T?